# Pass an id when creating a factory object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

I would like to know how to pass an id when creating a factory for my rspec tests.  At the moment I can create 'portfolio' attributes for example when there is no association, but I am not sure when there are associations.. Example being my current setup

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :portfolio_sectors
has_many :sectors, through: :portfolio_sectors


attr_accessible :overview, :title, :url, :sector_ids, :image_id, :images_attributes

#Validations
validates :title, :presence => {:message => 'Add your Title'}
validates :url, :presence => {:message => 'Add a URL'}
validates :overview, :presence => {:message => 'Add an Overview'}
#NOT SURE ON THIS BELOW
validates :sector_ids, :presence => {:message => 'Choose At Least 1 Sector'}


class PortfolioSector < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :portfolio
belongs_to :sector
end
```

So far creating a factory for a portfolio object consists of this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :portfolio do
   id 1
   overview "MyText"
   title "MyText"
   url "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
   sector_id 2
 end
end
```

and my spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Portfolio do

it "has a valid factory" do
 expect(FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio)).to be_valid
end

it "is successful with all attributes" do
  portfolio = FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio)
  expect(portfolio).to be_valid
end

it "is invalid with no Title" do 
 portfolio = FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio, title: nil)
 expect(portfolio).to have(1).errors_on(:title)
end

it "is invalid with no url" do 
 portfolio = FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio, url: nil)
 expect(portfolio).to have(1).errors_on(:url)
end

it "is invalid with no Overview" do 
 portfolio = FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio, overview: nil)
 expect(portfolio).to have(1).errors_on(:overview)
end

it "is invalid with no Sector_id" do 
 portfolio = FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio, sector_ids: '')
 expect(portfolio).to have(1).errors_on(:sector_ids)
end

end
```

I get this error when running the test though

```
2) Portfolio has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio)).to be_valid
   expected #<Portfolio id: 1, overview: "MyText", title: "MyText", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, sector_id: 2, url: "http://www.bbc.co.uk", slug: "mytext"> to be valid, but got errors: Sector ids Choose At Least 1 Sector
 # ./spec/models/portfolio_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the best way to deal with this association type and test it?

Thanks

UPDATE

So i just tried this, but feel its a bit long winded and hacky

Firstly I updated my factory object to

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :portfolio do
   id 1
   overview "MyText"
   title "MyText"
   url "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
   sector_ids 2  #changed this to sector_ids
 end
end
```

and then in my test database created some sectors, one of which does have the id 2 assigned to it..not the best way im sure?

Comment: show you spec there you test `build(:portfolio)).to be_valid` `build` not saved object & `be_valid` test on database writes

Comment: It seems the problem is in `sector_ids`... have you try to assing not `sector_ids` directly, but indirectly, like: `sectors { create_list( :sector, 1 ) }`. Note that you shell have the `:sector` factory already.

Comment: Also strong advice: don't assing system rails field directly, like: `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`...

Comment: Have you need an asnwer yet?

Comment: an answer would help, well more like an example really, not sure what you mean by the comments alone, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is in `sector_ids`. have you try to assing not sector_ids directly, but indirectly, like: `sectors { create_list( :sector, 1 ) }`, or as it has been shewn below. Note that you shell have the *`:sector`* factory already defined.

Additional strong advice: don't assing the system rails fields directly such as: *`id`*, *`created_at`*, *`updated_at`*. So the code shell be:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :sector do
      # some setups ....
   end

   factory :portfolio do
      overview "MyText"
      title "MyText"
      url "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
      ignore do
         sectors_count 0
      end
      after( :create ) do| portfolio, evaluator |
         create_list( :sector, evaluator.sectors_count, portfolio: portfolio )
      end
   end
end
```

And usage:

```
create( :portfolio ).sectors.length # 0
create( :portfolio, sectors_count: 15 ).sectors.length # 15
```